# not working visual tab when use wp_editor function in wordpress

Tags: php

i develop below code in wordpress:

wp_editor( 'ss', 'id', array() );

i use above code to create a metabox in custom post type.

this code create successfully TinyMCE editor wordpress but can't type any text in box! how to fix issue?

please help me...

Thank's

can't type in box area editor.